# Can't output line by line with print(var,end='')

Tags: python

I wrote a code for ping a host on cross-platform system.

The code's content is as below:

```
import psutil
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["ping -c 5 8.8.8.8"],shell=True)
for x in range(5):
    getLoading = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
    print(str(getLoading),end='<--')

print('done')
```

I expected I could have the result as below:

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=5ms
5.0<--
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=5ms
4.5<--
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=5ms
4.1<--
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=5ms
3.5<--    
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=5ms
4.0<--
done
```

I got the result I expected on Windows7/python3.4.3,   But failed result on CentOS 6.5/python3.4.3.
The result on Linux looks like as below:

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=5ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=5ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=5ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=5ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=5ms
5.0<--4.5<--4.1<--3.5<--4.0<--done
```

Could any python expert help me to figure out the root cause?
Thanks.

Comment: you have a couple errors I see immediately: `for x in range(5)` needs `:` and `print(done)` should be `print('done')`

Comment: Hi, Scott. Thanks for your reply quickly. That's typo. I fixed it. But it is not the root cause for the fail result.

Comment: I realize that, just wanted it to be correct.

Comment: Hi,Scott. I understood. Thanks for picking up my carelessness.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of the print function "buffering" some data then writing it after. 
I have had the same kind of issues while using print in my code. To avoid this kind of issues I would use a logger, this will immediately print the code

```
import logging
FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(
    format=FORMAT, level=logging.DEBUG, datefmt='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


import psutil
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["ping -c 5 8.8.8.8"], shell=True)
for x in range(5):
    getLoading = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
    logger.info(str(getLoading) + '<--')

logger.info('done')
```

Comment: Yes you are right; There **will** be a little buffering going on so there *will* be a slight delay in the output; but I don't think that's the problem the OP is having per se :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read from the process's stdout and have a bit of control over it so you can do some in-line printing of the "process load" as well.

**Example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import psutil
import subprocess

try:
    range = xrange
except NameError:
    pass


p = subprocess.Popen(["ping",  "-c", "5", "8.8.8.8"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()

for line in p.stdout:
    load = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
    print("{0:s}{1:0.2f}<--".format(line.decode(encoding), load))
print("done")
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./foo.py 
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
21.10<--
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=15.6 ms
15.40<--
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=15.6 ms
13.20<--
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=15.6 ms
20.70<--
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=15.5 ms
19.90<--
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=52 time=15.6 ms
11.00<--

19.50<--
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
17.40<--
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4007ms
12.90<--
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.596/15.629/15.669/0.114 ms
16.60<--
done
```

**NB:** This is written for Python 2/3 compatibility.

Comment: I'm getting `print("{0:s}{1:0.2f}<--".format(line, load))
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__`

Comment: Yes sorry fixed that; See update. The reason is that ``line`` is a ``bytes`` string so it needs to be decoded since we're using a ``str`` and ``str.format()``.

Comment: Very cool James.  Don't know why you just got -1'ed, but +1 for teaching me something cool.

Comment: I wish whoever downvoted had given me an extra half a minute to fix the error *damnit*! :)

Comment: @JamesMills, James, you know, this is the problem of SO - you was trying to post your answer the very first one to get more reputation but you didn't verify your code before posting. A lot of people are just adding useless small responses (I don't mean you) to be the first and after they are modifying it to be correct one. Isn't this unfair?

Comment: Grossly unfair ; yes :) For me it's about the quality; not the speediness of the response! To be fair I didn't test it on Python 3.4 (*even though I have it installed*); but I **did** test it on Python 2.7 :) Like I said; minor trivial fix!